# What is the best design for Sharing Data over the Objects?

Tags: java

I would like to share data between the objects.
Actually, for example, there is a World composed of Water and Individuals.
I would like the Individuals to access the Water.
I looked at transforming the Individual table in Collection, or making the Water a Singleton, but really, what would be the best design? 
(we might have multi threading processes on the Individual object... So we might need a Thread safe implementation.)
(Also, I wonder about passing by argument or instantiate the Water for each Individuals, but it seems not to be the most efficient implementation (processing instantiation) ?...)

A simple set of objects in order to fix the ideas (this set does not share the Water at all, the Individuals display 'null' here) :

```
package myworld.testing;

public class World {

    static Water evolution;
    static Individual [] tribe;

    public World(){
        evolution=new Water();
    }
    public static Water getWater(){
        return evolution;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        evolution=new Water();
        System.out.println("info "+evolution.get());
        tribe = new Individual[10];
        for(Individual individual : tribe){
            System.out.println("trace "+individual);
        }

        evolution=new Water("sprakly");
        System.out.println("info "+evolution.get());
        for(Individual individual : tribe){
            System.out.println("trace "+individual);
        }

        evolution.set("salty");
        System.out.println("info "+evolution.get());
        for(Individual individual : tribe){
            System.out.println("trace "+individual);
        }
    }

}

package myworld.testing;

public class Individual {
    int data;
    public Individual(){
        data=0;
    }
    public Individual(int i){
        data=i;
    }
    public void set(int i){
        data=i;
    }
    public int get(){
        return data;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return World.getWater().get()+" "+data;
    }
}

package myworld.testing;

public class Water {
    private static Water instance = null;
    String type;
    public static Water getInstance(){
        if(instance == null) {
             instance = new Water();
          }
          return instance;
    }
    public Water(){
        type="1";
    }
    public Water(String str){
        type=str;
    }
    public void set(String str){
        type=str;
    }
    public String get(){
        return type;
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help and advice in advance.
Feel free to share your thoughts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your getting `null` values while iterating over the array of `Individual`s is that, for each array element, you haven't created an instance whose reference will occupy it. Instantiating an array merely creates a sequential memory block of `null` pointers. The correct solution is:

```
tribe = new Individual[10];
for(int i = 0; i < tribe.length; i++) {
    tribe[i] = new Individual();
}
```

In regards to your question about "individuals accessing the water," you must declare the encapsulated instance of `Water` in `World` with the [public](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) visibility modifier to grant access to all classes outside the package containing `World`.

Given that `Individual` and `World` reside in the same package, using the `public` modifier isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @blackcompe. Agreed, and very true. The purpose though, is to instantiate the `Water` only once in the `World` and just have an access to this object from the `Individual`s. The `Individual`s being instantiated in the `World`.
And my wonder is : what would be the best design for this purpose.
I will work on the encapsulation.
Thanks again for your help.